# JAXB generates class twice for complextype and element ref from XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

My scenario: **complexType** and an **element** that **aliases** this complexType (they have different name). Both of them has **annotation** **documentation**.

This results in **Status.java and StatusType.java** with the exact same content. (Only one of them with XmlRootElement)

```
<xs:element name="Status" type="Status_Type">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Some docs.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="Status_Type">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Some docs.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <!-- some elements -->
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

However, when I **remove** only the annotation **documentation** from element, I only get **one** **generated** **Java** **class** which is actually the expected result!
How can I configure this behavior? :) I want to keep the XSD unchanged as is because it us supplied from a different vendor, not developed by our company, but I don't want class duplicates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We found two instances of typos as follows in the XSD:

```
<xs:element name="SomeElement" type="Boolean_Type"/>
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation xml:lang="hu">SomeDocs</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:element name="SomeOtherElement" type="Identifier_Type"/>
```

So annotation-doc element was at the same level of elements, not inside them. After fixing them JAXB build was success.